# Dataset Manipulation with Factors and Time variables in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataset, dplyr, apply

I have a simple question regarding data manipulation. Given the following dataset:

```
n = c("john","jane","tim","john","jimmy","tim","jane","john","jimmy")
s = c("2012-03-21","2013-02-12","2014-01-01","2012-05-21","2010-12-17","2012-01-21","2013-03-12","2013-08-21","2010-09-17")

df = data.frame(n,s)
     n      s
1  john 2012-03-21
2  jane 2013-02-12
3   tim 2014-01-01
4  john 2012-05-21
5 jimmy 2010-12-17
6   tim 2012-01-21
7  jane 2013-03-12
8  john 2013-08-21
9 jimmy 2010-09-17
```

I'd like to create a third column of data where for each person, I have calculated the number of months from their earliest time point. It would appear as follows:

```
         n      s        output
    1  john 2012-03-21     0
    2  jane 2013-02-12     0
    3   tim 2014-01-01     24
    4  john 2012-05-21     2
    5 jimmy 2010-12-17     3
    6   tim 2012-01-21     0
    7  jane 2013-03-12     1
    8  john 2013-08-21    17
    9 jimmy 2010-09-17     0
```

As you can see, with john for example, the earliest time point was 2012-03-21, so it calculated the number of months from 2012-03-21 to 2012-05-21, then to 2013-08-21 and placed the output in the appropriate row.

I thought dplyr or apply functions would come in handy but i'm finding I am crafting quite a large amount of code for something that shouldn't be too difficult.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why john's last point is 73.5? shouldn't `2013-08-21 - 2012-03-21` be 17?

Comment: Sorry was calculating these by hand and changed some dates to make it easier to see but must've forgot to change that output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can do:

```r
n = c("john","jane","tim","john","jimmy","tim","jane","john","jimmy")
s = c("2012-03-21","2013-02-12","2014-01-01","2012-05-21","2010-12-17","2012-01-21","2013-03-12","2013-08-21","2010-09-17")
s = as.Date(s)
df = data.frame(n,s)


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(n) %>% 
  mutate(out = round(as.integer(difftime(s, s[which.min(s)], units = 'days')) / 30, 0))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   n [4]
#>        n          s   out
#>   <fctr>     <date> <dbl>
#> 1   john 2012-03-21     0
#> 2   jane 2013-02-12     0
#> 3    tim 2014-01-01    24
#> 4   john 2012-05-21     2
#> 5  jimmy 2010-12-17     3
#> 6    tim 2012-01-21     0
#> 7   jane 2013-03-12     1
#> 8   john 2013-08-21    17
#> 9  jimmy 2010-09-17     0
```

As always it's tricky to calculate the number of months, as different month have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

In my answer, I use the `lubridate` package to ensure the `s` column in `df` doesn't get treated as strings or factors:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df$s = as_date(df$s)
```

Create a separate dataframe for start dates:

```
df.startdate = df %>% group_by(n) %>% summarise(start_date = min(s))
```

Now merge the main `df` onto the newly constructed `df.startdate`:

```
answer = merge(df, df.startdate, by = "n") %>% 
    mutate(output = interval(start_date, s) %/% months(1))
```

Comment: This worked great as well, unfortunately cannot mark more than one answer. Thank you for posting and helping with this!

Comment: @Tim Really?  I tend to upvote everyone who gives a good answer to my questions :(

Comment: Oops, you definitely deserve an upvote! It's been a while since I have been around here. Thanks again